# Uninstall Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried to reinstall(change from default to custom), but installation process hanged, so now I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 desplayed to be installed, but not existing and leading these way to installation fail(e. g. kb2999226, Silverlight 5 developer runtime required, MVS hub fail).
I tried to do:

1) Using RevoUninstaller uninstall all programs contain Visual studio in their name, programs which is from Visual Studio(like Azure, Asp), programs contain C(C++, Visual C) in their name and .Net programs.

2) Using same uninstaller apply force uninstallation to directories in Program files with names like in subject 1.

3) Totally remove from Windows\Microsoft.Net all directories with names containing "Visual Studio", totally remove all directories from c:\ProgramData\ProgramCache.

4) Delete all "Visual Studio" directory as well as all keys and values which contain "Visual Studio" from repository.

5) Apply standart installer with options /uninstall /force, /repair

6) Apply oficial MS TotalUninstaller(https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases).
I'm just loose whole my day. Guys, please advise me any way to uninstall(install back) VS without reinstalling Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 6). Did the Uninstaller not work? Also, you could try to "repair" the VS installation first?

Comment: Yeah, even after running Uninstaller with administrator priveleges I see a message that MVS Update 3 is already installed in installator. I mentioned in 5), that I tried /repair and repairing also fails.